# DIV getting resized but not the d3 pie chart and the legends

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing Donut Chart</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #first {
      height: 40%;
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid #73AD21 !important;
      position: absolute !important;
    }
    #chart {
      position: absolute;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
    }
    #chart legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    #first legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    .slice path {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .textTop {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
      fill: #2c3218;
    }
    .textBottom {
      fill: #444;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <svg id="chart" viewBox="0 0 960 500" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <div id="first">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var w = document.getElementById('first').clientWidth;
           // alert(w);
          var h = document.getElementById('first').clientHeight;
           // alert(h);
          var r = Math.min(w, h) / 2 - 10;
           // alert(r);
          var inner = 70;
          var color = d3.scale.category10();

          var data = [
            ["192.168.12.1", 20],
            ["76.09.45.34", 40],
            ["34.91.23.76", 80],
            ["192.168.19.32", 16],
            ["192.168.10.89", 50],
            ["192.178.34.07", 18],
            ["192.168.12.98", 30]
          ];

          var data = data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              IP: d[0],
              count: d[1]
            };
          });

          var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
            return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
          });

          var vis = d3.select("#first")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .data([data])
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + r * 1.5 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

          var textTop = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textTop")
            .text("TOTAL")
            .attr("y", -10),

            textBottom = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textBottom")
            .text(total)
            .attr("y", 10);

          var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner)
            .outerRadius(r);

          var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner + 0)
            .outerRadius(r + 1);

          var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .startAngle(1.1 * Math.PI)
            .endAngle(3.1 * Math.PI)
            .value(function(d) {
              return d.count;
            });

          var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "slice")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr("d", arcOver)
                .style('opacity', 0.5)

              textTop.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.IP)
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.count)
                .attr("y", 10);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style('opacity', 1);

              textTop.text("TOTAL")
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(total);
            });

          arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .transition()
            .ease("exp")
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

          function tweenPie(b) {
            var i = d3.interpolate({
              startAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI,
              endAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI
            }, b);
            return function(t) {
              return arc(i(t));
            };
          }

          var legend = vis.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+ r * 3/2 +", -"+ r +")")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("width", w / 2)
            .attr("height", h)
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
            });

          legend.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            });

          legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("font-size", "10px")
            .attr("font-family", "Segoe UI")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.IP;
            });
        </script>
      </div>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = $("#chart"),
      aspect = chart.width() / chart.height(),
      container = chart.parent();
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
      var targetWidth = container.width();
      chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
      chart.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
    }).trigger("resize");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The div size is getting resized according to screen size but the chart and legends are not getting fit into the div size accordingly. They are not responsive at all. I have already used jquery for this but I don't know what is the issue. The chart and the legend are not responding.
Any one please help me. I need help. I am stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you put a `<div>` inside an `<svg>` ??

Comment: And why a `<script>` inside a `<div>` inside a `<svg>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overdoing it.

The following lines:

```
#chart {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
[...]
<svg id="chart" viewBox="0 0 960 500" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
```

(that you already have) are enough to have a responsive svg. Within the svg, you don't have to care about the current width or height of the window: the `viewBox` ensures that the coordinates within [0,960] and [0,500] will are scaled to fit precisely the area assigned to the svg. So now you just have to remove extra stuff:

- remove any div or script within the svg
- use directly `d3.select("#chart")` instead of creating another `svg`
- use absolute coordinates: x=320 will always be at 1/3rd of the width, y=250 will always be at one half of the height

**Edit** Running example below. Notice how `w` and `h` have fixed values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing Donut Chart</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #chart {
      position: absolute;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid #73AD21 !important;
    }
    #chart legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    #first legend {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0%;
    }
    .slice path {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .textTop {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
      fill: #2c3218;
    }
    .textBottom {
      fill: #444;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <svg id="chart" viewBox="0 0 960 500" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
    </svg>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var w=960;
           // alert(w);
          var h=500;
           // alert(h);
          var r = Math.min(w, h) / 2 - 10;
           // alert(r);
          var inner = 70;
          var color = d3.scale.category10();

          var data = [
            ["192.168.12.1", 20],
            ["76.09.45.34", 40],
            ["34.91.23.76", 80],
            ["192.168.19.32", 16],
            ["192.168.10.89", 50],
            ["192.178.34.07", 18],
            ["192.168.12.98", 30]
          ];

          var data = data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              IP: d[0],
              count: d[1]
            };
          });

          var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
            return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
          });

          var vis = d3.select("#chart")
            .data([data])
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + r * 1.5 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

          var textTop = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textTop")
            .text("TOTAL")
            .attr("y", -10),

            textBottom = vis.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("class", "textBottom")
            .text(total)
            .attr("y", 10);

          var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner)
            .outerRadius(r);

          var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner + 0)
            .outerRadius(r + 1);

          var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .startAngle(1.1 * Math.PI)
            .endAngle(3.1 * Math.PI)
            .value(function(d) {
              return d.count;
            });

          var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "slice")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr("d", arcOver)
                .style('opacity', 0.5)

              textTop.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.IP)
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.count)
                .attr("y", 10);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
              d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(100)
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style('opacity', 1);

              textTop.text("TOTAL")
                .attr("y", -10);
              textBottom.text(total);
            });

          arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .transition()
            .ease("exp")
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

          function tweenPie(b) {
            var i = d3.interpolate({
              startAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI,
              endAngle: 1.1 * Math.PI
            }, b);
            return function(t) {
              return arc(i(t));
            };
          }

          var legend = vis.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+ r * 3/2 +", -"+ r +")")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("width", w / 2)
            .attr("height", h)
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
            });

          legend.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return color(i);
            });

          legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("font-size", "10px")
            .attr("font-family", "Segoe UI")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.IP;
            });
        </script>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = $("#chart"),
      aspect = chart.width() / chart.height(),
      container = chart.parent();
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
      var targetWidth = container.width();
      chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
      chart.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
    }).trigger("resize");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually the requirement is to put the chart and the legend inside a div nit on the browser window body. As soon as the div gets resized the chart and legend should display according to div.

Comment: The chart can still be inside a div, what I'm saying is that it cannot be the other way round. If you look at how the browser interprets your code, you'll see that "#first" is not inside "#chart" (but instead a new svg with fixed dimensions is created within "#first")

Comment: @RACHITAPATRO Is it better with the example?

Comment: Please tell me how to get the height and width of a svg.. I am always getting 0 when I try

Comment: `document.getElementById('chart').clientWidth` works. The problem is how you use this value.

Comment: As such I want that whatever the height and width of the div is to be automatically identified by the svg

Comment: 2 options: with css, using "width:100%" and "height:100%". By far the easiest way. Second option, with javascript: put an "onresize" event on the container, and each time it is triggered, compute the dimensions of the container to apply it to the svg. You'll need to learn a bit more about js and svg to make this work properly. The first option is the one used in my answer: is there anything else you want to achieve?